# Replace specific URL in string with php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

A string contains various urls like this:

```
http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=457
http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=11782
```

**Example with 1 URL:**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=457 consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
```

**Example with 2 URLs**

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=457 consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=11782 At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
```

The URLs inside the text must be replaced with new seo urls.

```
http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=457
```

becomes

```
http://www.example.com/this-ist-the-new-url.html
```

The Seo URLs will be generatred by a function.

How is it possible to search and replace the FULL url with a other URL inside a string when the URL contains this:

```
http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I believe you're looking for "url rewrite rule". Take a look at this article. https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: Hi, no, i know how to rewrite. I have already a function. I am looking for a functions to replace the URL with the new URL. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function below is looking for a perfect match in a string. It doesn't matter if something is there before or after the string as long as the given characters are there in order.

```
$phrase  = "Whatever you write here it can be replaced";
$replacethis = array("you", "can", "replaced");
$withtis   = array("I", "can't", "placed");

$newphrase = str_replace($replacethis, $whithis, $phrase);
```

And `$newphrase` would be: *Whatever I write here it can't be placed*

In your case it would be:

```
$phrase  = "Whatever you write here it can be replaced";
$replacethis = array("http://www.example.com/viewtopic.php?f=36&t=457");
$withtis   = array("http://www.example.com/this-ist-the-new-url.html");

$newphrase = str_replace($replacethis, $whithis, $phrase);
```

Comment: hi, thank you. I know how str_replace is working. The problem is that the URL is various. So there is no exact match.

Comment: Alright than. extract the urls from the webpage with a tool like [this](http://tools.buzzstream.com/link-building-extract-urls).After that you going to have a list what you can use to create a for loop to replace the urls individually.